# How can I require at least one to be selected for angular material toggle with multiple options?

Tags: angular, angular-material, togglebutton, preventdefault

I want the user to be able to select multiple options, but if there is only one choice, how can I prevent to select this button deselecting?

HTML:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group (change)="changeOpt($event)" multiple name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
    <mat-button-toggle value="opt1" [checked]="true">Opt1</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="opt2" [checked]="true">Opt2</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="opt3" [checked]="true">Opt3</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

TS:

```
changeOpt(evt: any) {
    if (evt.value.length === 1) {
        // PreventDefault
    }
}
```

I wanted to prevent by looking at the total number of selections as above but I could not

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqevjt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-toggle-appearance-example.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want "avoid" that no button selected -not only give an error message-:

You need know about [data binding](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#data-binding). Angular supports one and two-way data binding. That's: the variables in .ts (the model) it's showed in the .html (the view). And change in inputs in .html can be change a variable in .ts

So, we are using [(ngModel)] to give value to a one variable in .ts

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [(ngModel)]="value" multiple 
     name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
    <mat-button-toggle value="opt1" (change)="change($event)">Opt1</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="opt2" (change)="change($event)">Opt2</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="opt3" (change)="change($event)">Opt3</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

The function change, check the length of "value", if is 1, store in a variable the value, if is 0 recover the variable

```
change(evt: any) {
    if (this.value.length === 1)
      this.oldValue = this.value[0];

    if (this.value.length === 0) 
      this.value = [this.oldValue];

  }
```

See in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqevjt-2kmbmx?file=src/app/button-toggle-appearance-example.ts)

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this using the form validator `Validators.maxLength` inside of a `formGroup`, for example:

```
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
  <mat-button-toggle-group formControlName="items" (change)="changeOpt($event)" multiple name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
      <mat-button-toggle value="opt1" [checked]="true">Opt1</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="opt2" [checked]="true">Opt2</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="opt3" [checked]="true">Opt3</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</form>

{{ exampleForm.controls.items.value }}
{{ exampleForm.controls.items.value.length }}

{{ exampleForm.valid }}
```

and

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'button-toggle-appearance-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-toggle-appearance-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-toggle-appearance-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonToggleAppearanceExample implements OnInit {
  exampleForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: [null, Validators.maxLength(1)]
    });
  }
}
```

I think is enough. At the moment you choose more that one options `.valid` will raise to false.

Comment: maxLength and minLength it's only applied to strings, not to an array (and a mat-button-toggle-group give you an array)